# Stop earlier a reduce operation in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, break

Is there a way to "break" a reduce operation in Spark?

Let's say I want to do this:

```
var result: Int = 0
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    if (/*Some condition on result*/) {
        result = someFunction(result, iterator.next())
    } else {
        break
    }
}
```

The way to do it in Spark would be to `reduce` a RDD (containing what the iterator returns):

```
rdd.reduce((result, next) =>
    if (/*Some condition on result*/) someFunction(result, next)
    else result
)
```

But what if computing the condition is expensive? I could do this:

```
//result is now of type (Int, Boolean) and the initial Boolean is true
rdd.reduce((result, next) =>
    if (result._2 && /*Some condition on result*/) (someFunction(result._1, next._1), true)
    else (result._1, false)
)
```

Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Does this have to be done in spark? An RDD isn't necessarily ordered any specific way, so there isn't really semantic meaning to "breaking" half way through a reduce. If you really need to you can iterate through each partition, but unless you collect your RDD into a List or something there isn't necessarily a meaningful ordering to your data across partitions.

Comment: You're right, I'm kinda new to Spark, I was wondering that out of curiosity even if that seemed a bit "un-spark-ish". But this question does not even make sense now that you point out the unordered property of Spark. Should I delete it?

Comment: It's a good question still, there's no way to know that unless you ask, and surely other people will find it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you want to do doesn't necessarily fit into spark's computation model. Because the data is split across partitions, there isn't necessarily a well defined order. If you weren't using spark, the appropriate function call would be `takeWhile`.

```
val data: List[DType] = ...
...
data.takeWhile(condition).map(someFunction)
```

You can almost get this in spark with mapPartitions. That applies a function to an iterator over each partition.

```
val data: RDD[DType] = ...
...
data.mapPartitions(partitionData: Iterator[DType] => partitionData.takeWhile(condition).map(someFunction))
```